# Requests in Angular 8

Tags: angular

How can we make an endpoint accept the request as we do in Django like

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path("view/<id:str>", include(views.urls))
]
```

I am trying to create a blog which has an end-point "view" which I want to show the post according to the id specified like

```
http://localhost:4200/view/32
```

Then the post corresponding to "32" will be shown up in the DOM.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/router#route-definition-with-a-parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set this entry in your router config:

```
{ path: 'view/:id', component: ViewComponent }
```

And then access the `id` with:

```
constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.params.subscribe( params => {
    this.id = params.id;
    console.log(this.id) 
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a component. E.g. `ProductComponent` is your view and then in `app.module.ts`(or another module) you should write your routing:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ProductFormComponent,
    AdminProductComponent,
    AdminOrderComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([          
      { path: 'products/:id',
        component: ProductComponent
      },
      { path: 'admin/products',
        component: AdminProductComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'admin/orders',
        component: AdminOrderComponent
      }
    ])
  ]      
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Let's see this path: `path: 'products/:id'`, where `products/` is your view(like in Django)
and `:id` is `id` of your item(`product`)

[More info can be seen here in Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#route-definition-with-a-parameter)

Answer (score 0):

You can put an component on a route in your `rouing.module`.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: FirstComponent},
  {path: 'tools/:article', component: ViewComponent}
  ];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [
    {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'}
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

you can then in your ViewComponent acces the article number

you'll need to call activated route in the constructor

```
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute)
```

and then subscribe it in your ngOnInit

```
 this.route.params.subscribe(result => { 
    console.log(result.article)}
```